# RethinkDB struggles with 1.5k writes on i3.Metal instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rethinkdb

I have been benchmarking RethinkDB's performance on an i3.Metal ec2 instance, with all 8 nvme SSD's in a raid 0, and am finding the performance to be lacking.

The setup I have is 3 clients subscribed to the changes of a table. Then one client progressively increases it's writes per second, which get sent to the other two clients via a changefeed.

This setup can reach about 1.5k writes a second before it starts to get erratic and lag. If I don't have any clients, and no changefeed subscriptions I can get about 2.5k writes a second.

There were benchmarks which showed RethinkDB getting roughly 8k read/writes per node on inferior hardware. I am just wondering is there some special way to configure the i3.metal to get better performance? Or is there an entirely different cloud service that will provide better RethinkDB performance?